# Time Tracking Tool Window in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA there is a [Time Tracking Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/time-tracking-tool-window.html) which provides ways to start and stop timers for the active task, which I'm looking forward to use it as a time tracker for my projects.

Where is this option located in Android Studio? Because I have tried to find it out but there's no `Time Tracking` option in the `Tool Windows`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time tracking is currently available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. Since it's not an open-source component, it is not available in Android Studio.

Answer (score 7):

I am using 2 free time-tracking plugins on Android Studio:

1) darkyen

https://github.com/Darkyenus/DarkyenusTimeTracker

2) wakatime

https://wakatime.com/

Wakatime is comprehensive and has a subscription model for additional features.

You can install them easily from Android Studio -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browser Repositories.

Comment: Thank you. Can you actually post a link for option 1) darkyen? Because I couldn't find it.

Comment: Sure, here it is https://github.com/Darkyenus/DarkyenusTimeTracker .   I will add links also to the main answer